# Вывод списка процессов через tasklist с загрузкой цп в процентах

Tags: windows, cmd, администрирование, bat

Пишу скрипт для задачи: вывод списка процессов, которые за определённый период времени нагружали цп больше определённого процента. Я не могу найти команду, чтобы вывести процессы с загрузкой цп в процентах через cmd. В powershell то же самое: выводится только информация о процессорном времени.
Как можно через tasklist или get-process вывести процессы с загрузкой цп в процентах?

Comment: Из инструментов можно выбрать регулярный запуск скриптов через планировщик задач с обращением к WMI, tasklist и т.д. Можно использовать агентов мониторинга типа Zabbix agent. Но есть стандартное средство контроля: [Счетчики производительности](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/perfctrs/performance-counters-portal)

Comment: Смотреть [EventCounters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counters). Можно использовать [dotnet tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters). Можно вызывать в PowerShell: [Get-Counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-7.4).

Answer (score 0):

```
:: id процесса, % использования
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get idProcess, PercentProcessorTime
```

Теперь парсим:

```
:core
@set "DATE="&@set "TIME="&@set "CD="&@set "RANDOM="
@set "_T.I_processId="&@set "_T.I_cpuUsage="
@set "_T.F_wmicData=%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%"^
     "%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%DATE%%TIME%%RANDOM:~0,2%%RANDOM:~-2%"
  @set "_T.F_wmicData=%_T.F_wmicData: =0%"
  @set "_T.F_wmicData=%_T.F_wmicData:/=%"
  @set "_T.F_wmicData=%_T.F_wmicData:\=%"
  @set "_T.F_wmicData=%_T.F_wmicData:;=%"
  @set "_T.F_wmicData=%_T.F_wmicData::=%"
  @set "_T.F_wmicData=%_T.F_wmicData:.=%"
  @set "_T.F_wmicData=%_T.F_wmicData:,=%"
  @set "_T.F_wmicData=%_T.F_wmicData:-=%"
  @set "_T.F_wmicData=%_T.F_wmicData:_=%"
@set "_T.F_wmicData=%LocalAppData%\Temp\%_T.F_wmicData:~-32%"
  @call "%WinDir%\System32\WBEM\wmic.exe" path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process ^
    get idProcess,PercentProcessorTime /format:list >"%_T.F_wmicData%"
    @for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%S IN ('@type "%_T.F_wmicData%" ^
        | @call "%WinDir%\System32\find.exe" /i "="') do @call :data %%S
  @del /q /f "%_T.F_wmicData%" >NUL 2>NUL.
@goto exit

:data
@if "%~1"=="IDProcess" (@set "_T.I_processId=%~2"&@goto exit) else (@set "_T.I_cpuUsage=%~2"&@goto main)

:main
@echo process %_T.I_processId% uses %_T.I_cpuUsage%%%
@goto exit

:exit
```

`PowerShell` из-под `cmd`:

```
@call "%WinDir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" ^
      -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "Get-Process|Format-List Id,CPU"
```

`win:Taskmgr.exe`, как видно, показывает информацию адекватнее.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217579/0xdb, спасибо за редактирование:
`P:\example>z Непредвиденное появление: |. P:\example>        | @call "C:\WINDOWS\System32\find.exe" /i "="') do @call :data %S P:\example>c ` (рецепт для -в-с-е-х- тех у кого не работает редактированная версия ответа - убрать 4 строчку, а 3-ю заменить на `%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%CD%%DATE%%TIME%%RANDOM:~0,2%%RANDOM:~-2%"` <- как ни странно, это и было изменение ответа; зачем?)

Comment: К слову, я не пишу варианты с `^` т.к. их не обернуть без `@echo off` в `@for` цикл минуя лишний вывод (может настало время сделать `echo off` подобное в `JS`? <- о том, насколько стрёмная это тема; потому везде `@`).